# How to get specific variables out of data

Tags: haskell

I want to create a function that will allow me to take the data Title out of a book, below is the data type creation

```
data Novel =
   title String
   year Int
   bought Bool
deriving show

data Novel
title String
year Int
bought Bool
deriving show
```

And I want to create a function that will getTitle that will get the title

```
getTitle :: Novel -> String
getTitle = undefined
```

aswell as be able to change the bought variable with a function setBought

```
setBought:: Person -> String -> Person
setBought = undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

First, get the syntax right:

```
data Novel = Novel
  { title :: String
  , year :: Int
  , bought :: Bool }
 deriving (Show)
```

Now, despite what the signatures seem to say, `title` is *not* a variable of type `String`, but it's actually an accessor function:

```
Prelude> :t title
title :: Novel -> String
```

So there's your `getTitle` right there, no need to define anything.

As for `setBought`, ...erm, what's `Person`? At any rate, there's two things you can do with a data type for “changes”:

- Fully match on a constructor and put it back again. Like

  ```
  f :: Novel -> ...
  f (Novel t y b) = ... (Novel _ _ _) ...
  ```
- Use *record update* syntax

  ```
  f :: Novel -> ...
  f book = ... book{ year=_ } ...
  ```

An entirely different way of dealing with records is the [lens library](https://github.com/ekmett/lens#lens-lenses-folds-and-traversals).